# Why resizing a specific svg not working with CSS

Tags: html, css, svg

In the following example, I would like to understand why the `.tag-buy` content svg does not have its width and height at 60px while in HTML it works.

With another svg on the `.tag-work` class it works, yet the two look identical ...

I tried with the `background-image` property, same result ...

Property `transform: scale(XX)` on `.tag-buy` increase it but but I would have preferred to use the width and height and especially to understand why sometimes it works for certain svg and sometimes not :)

```css
body { 
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper { 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 80px; 
  background-color: #FFF; 
}

.tag-buy::after {
  content: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="60px" width="60px" viewbox="0 0 32 32"><path d="M28.273 12.397h-7.089v-3.676c0-2.817-2.288-5.121-5.104-5.121s-5.104 2.304-5.104 5.121v3.676h-7.296c-0.884 0-1.6 0.717-1.6 1.601 0 0.304 0.085 0.588 0.232 0.83l-0.004-0.007 6.172 13.58h14.88l6.285-13.58c0.145-0.24 0.275-0.522 0.275-0.823 0-0.884-0.763-1.6-1.647-1.6zM5.28 15.598h5.6l0.615 4.001h-4.329zM10.080 26l-1.92-4.001h3.705l0.615 4.001h-2.4zM17.28 26h-2.56l-0.64-4.001h3.84zM18.24 19.598h-4.32l-0.64-4.001h5.44zM18.784 12.397h-5.406l-0.004-3.676c-0-0.004-0-0.009-0-0.013 0-1.494 1.211-2.706 2.706-2.706s2.706 1.211 2.706 2.706c0 0.005 0 0.009-0 0.014v-0.001zM21.92 26h-2.41l0.65-4.001h3.68zM24.834 19.598h-4.376l0.502-4.001h5.605z"/></svg>');
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}

.tag-buy-bg::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 32 32" ><path d="M28.273 12.397h-7.089v-3.676c0-2.817-2.288-5.121-5.104-5.121s-5.104 2.304-5.104 5.121v3.676h-7.296c-0.884 0-1.6 0.717-1.6 1.601 0 0.304 0.085 0.588 0.232 0.83l-0.004-0.007 6.172 13.58h14.88l6.285-13.58c0.145-0.24 0.275-0.522 0.275-0.823 0-0.884-0.763-1.6-1.647-1.6zM5.28 15.598h5.6l0.615 4.001h-4.329zM10.080 26l-1.92-4.001h3.705l0.615 4.001h-2.4zM17.28 26h-2.56l-0.64-4.001h3.84zM18.24 19.598h-4.32l-0.64-4.001h5.44zM18.784 12.397h-5.406l-0.004-3.676c-0-0.004-0-0.009-0-0.013 0-1.494 1.211-2.706 2.706-2.706s2.706 1.211 2.706 2.706c0 0.005 0 0.009-0 0.014v-0.001zM21.92 26h-2.41l0.65-4.001h3.68zM24.834 19.598h-4.376l0.502-4.001h5.605z"/></svg>');
  background-size: 60px 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}

.tag-work:after {
    content: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12 2C6.5 2 2 6.5 2 12s4.5 10 10 10 10-4.5 10-10S17.5 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.4 0-8-3.6-8-8s3.6-8 8-8 8 3.6 8 8-3.6 8-8 8zm3.9-11.7L10 14.2l-1.9-1.9c-.4-.4-1-.4-1.4 0s-.4 1 0 1.4l2.6 2.6c.4.4 1 .4 1.4 0l6.6-6.6c.4-.4.4-1 0-1.4-.4-.4-1-.4-1.4 0z"/></svg>');
    display: inline-block;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper tag-buy">
</div>

<div class="wrapper tag-buy-bg">
</div>

<div class="wrapper tag-work">
</div>

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="60px" height="60px" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<path d="M28.273 12.397h-7.089v-3.676c0-2.817-2.288-5.121-5.104-5.121s-5.104 2.304-5.104 5.121v3.676h-7.296c-0.884 0-1.6 0.717-1.6 1.601 0 0.304 0.085 0.588 0.232 0.83l-0.004-0.007 6.172 13.58h14.88l6.285-13.58c0.145-0.24 0.275-0.522 0.275-0.823 0-0.884-0.763-1.6-1.647-1.6zM5.28 15.598h5.6l0.615 4.001h-4.329zM10.080 26l-1.92-4.001h3.705l0.615 4.001h-2.4zM17.28 26h-2.56l-0.64-4.001h3.84zM18.24 19.598h-4.32l-0.64-4.001h5.44zM18.784 12.397h-5.406l-0.004-3.676c-0-0.004-0-0.009-0-0.013 0-1.494 1.211-2.706 2.706-2.706s2.706 1.211 2.706 2.706c0 0.005 0 0.009-0 0.014v-0.001zM21.92 26h-2.41l0.65-4.001h3.68zM24.834 19.598h-4.376l0.502-4.001h5.605z"></path>
</svg>
```

Thx

Comment: TRY THE SCALE COMMAND

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is because you have a bad `viewBox` attribute.  It is supposed to be `viewBox`, not `viewbox`.

The reason why the inline one works is because inline SVGs are parsed using HTML parsing rules, which are forgiving of case.  But the first two are are parsed using normal XML rules, which means that element and attribute names are case sensitive.

```css
body { 
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper { 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 80px; 
  background-color: #FFF; 
}

.tag-buy::after {
  content: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="60px" width="60px" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><path d="M28.273 12.397h-7.089v-3.676c0-2.817-2.288-5.121-5.104-5.121s-5.104 2.304-5.104 5.121v3.676h-7.296c-0.884 0-1.6 0.717-1.6 1.601 0 0.304 0.085 0.588 0.232 0.83l-0.004-0.007 6.172 13.58h14.88l6.285-13.58c0.145-0.24 0.275-0.522 0.275-0.823 0-0.884-0.763-1.6-1.647-1.6zM5.28 15.598h5.6l0.615 4.001h-4.329zM10.080 26l-1.92-4.001h3.705l0.615 4.001h-2.4zM17.28 26h-2.56l-0.64-4.001h3.84zM18.24 19.598h-4.32l-0.64-4.001h5.44zM18.784 12.397h-5.406l-0.004-3.676c-0-0.004-0-0.009-0-0.013 0-1.494 1.211-2.706 2.706-2.706s2.706 1.211 2.706 2.706c0 0.005 0 0.009-0 0.014v-0.001zM21.92 26h-2.41l0.65-4.001h3.68zM24.834 19.598h-4.376l0.502-4.001h5.605z"/></svg>');
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}

.tag-buy-bg::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32" ><path d="M28.273 12.397h-7.089v-3.676c0-2.817-2.288-5.121-5.104-5.121s-5.104 2.304-5.104 5.121v3.676h-7.296c-0.884 0-1.6 0.717-1.6 1.601 0 0.304 0.085 0.588 0.232 0.83l-0.004-0.007 6.172 13.58h14.88l6.285-13.58c0.145-0.24 0.275-0.522 0.275-0.823 0-0.884-0.763-1.6-1.647-1.6zM5.28 15.598h5.6l0.615 4.001h-4.329zM10.080 26l-1.92-4.001h3.705l0.615 4.001h-2.4zM17.28 26h-2.56l-0.64-4.001h3.84zM18.24 19.598h-4.32l-0.64-4.001h5.44zM18.784 12.397h-5.406l-0.004-3.676c-0-0.004-0-0.009-0-0.013 0-1.494 1.211-2.706 2.706-2.706s2.706 1.211 2.706 2.706c0 0.005 0 0.009-0 0.014v-0.001zM21.92 26h-2.41l0.65-4.001h3.68zM24.834 19.598h-4.376l0.502-4.001h5.605z"/></svg>');
  background-size: 60px 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}

.tag-work:after {
    content: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12 2C6.5 2 2 6.5 2 12s4.5 10 10 10 10-4.5 10-10S17.5 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.4 0-8-3.6-8-8s3.6-8 8-8 8 3.6 8 8-3.6 8-8 8zm3.9-11.7L10 14.2l-1.9-1.9c-.4-.4-1-.4-1.4 0s-.4 1 0 1.4l2.6 2.6c.4.4 1 .4 1.4 0l6.6-6.6c.4-.4.4-1 0-1.4-.4-.4-1-.4-1.4 0z"/></svg>');
    display: inline-block;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper tag-buy">
</div>

<div class="wrapper tag-buy-bg">
</div>

<div class="wrapper tag-work">
</div>

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="60px" height="60px" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<path d="M28.273 12.397h-7.089v-3.676c0-2.817-2.288-5.121-5.104-5.121s-5.104 2.304-5.104 5.121v3.676h-7.296c-0.884 0-1.6 0.717-1.6 1.601 0 0.304 0.085 0.588 0.232 0.83l-0.004-0.007 6.172 13.58h14.88l6.285-13.58c0.145-0.24 0.275-0.522 0.275-0.823 0-0.884-0.763-1.6-1.647-1.6zM5.28 15.598h5.6l0.615 4.001h-4.329zM10.080 26l-1.92-4.001h3.705l0.615 4.001h-2.4zM17.28 26h-2.56l-0.64-4.001h3.84zM18.24 19.598h-4.32l-0.64-4.001h5.44zM18.784 12.397h-5.406l-0.004-3.676c-0-0.004-0-0.009-0-0.013 0-1.494 1.211-2.706 2.706-2.706s2.706 1.211 2.706 2.706c0 0.005 0 0.009-0 0.014v-0.001zM21.92 26h-2.41l0.65-4.001h3.68zM24.834 19.598h-4.376l0.502-4.001h5.605z"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was going to go crazy !!